# How to create a DataSource in SpringBoot 2?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I try to access a DataSource bean, declared as:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.customer.datasource.properties")
public DataSource customerDataSource() {
    return customerDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(DataSource.class).build();
}
```

This works in Spring Boot 1.5 but if fails in Spring Boot 2.5 with the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:75)
at demo.customer.CustomerConfig.customerDataSource(CustomerConfig.java:55)
at demo.customer.CustomerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1637ca06.CGLIB$customerDataSource$4(<generated>)
at demo.customer.CustomerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1637ca06$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50f070a1.invoke(<generated>)
```

I also tried hardcoding the parameters (see below), but the error changed to NullPointerException.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource customerDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:customers");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

The NPE exception I get is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.determineDatabaseDialectClass(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:185)   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.buildJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:143)     
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:127)   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:346)   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
....
```

I also see the same NPE if I choose ".type(HikariDataSource.class)".

Do you have any idea what changed since version 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a configuration class and register a bean like below :

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

You can also provide the values in `application.yml` or `application.properties` in springboot if you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as dependency and springboot will automatically create the datasource bean for you.
**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:your:url
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

For your case , the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.determineDatabaseDialectClass(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:185)
```

occurs because the method `determineDatabaseDialectClass()` returns the Hibernate database dialect class, or null if none found.

Official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.html#determineDatabaseDialectClass-org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database-)

So,try adding the following in application.properties to set the dialect or add it programatically :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

or using a programatically using bean like :

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource( this.restDataSource() );
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan( new String[ ] { "com.jverstry" } );
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("MyMy");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect",  "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);
        return factoryBean;
    }
```

Usually springoot by default takes care of this and provides default implementation for this , if you have provided all the values in the property files etc. You could also configure this through xml but since it is springboot configurations through java are much appreciated.

Comment: This is exactly what I did as 2nd option when I hardcoded the parameters in customerDataSource. I get a NullPonterException.

Comment: @user3429660 Sorry missed that part,have updated the answer

Comment: thanks for looking into this. After adding hibernate.dialect I see the exact same errors. :(

Comment: @user3429660Basically there is some configuration issue in your code ,otherwise the default implementation should have worked fine.Try setting it through bean creation ,i have provided an example.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ananthapadmanabhan's answer, here is the code I finally used:

```
@Bean
public DataSource orderDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:orders");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}

@Bean(name = "orderEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setDataSource(this.orderDataSource());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("demo.order");
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("order");

    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager orderTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory orderEntityManager) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(orderEntityManager);
}
```